# TYPO3: How to use Extbase with external database

Tags: typo3, extbase

An extbase extension shall select data from an external non-typo3 database and display them in TYPO3 frontend. Updating data or insertion of new data is not planned. It is not allowed to store the external data in the local TYPO3 system. The data are relational, and the external database is physically on an external server.

Upto now a pibase extension was used for this. The funcionality shall now be replaced by an extbase extension.

How can the external database be accessed with extbase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a helper utility which can send SQL SELECT requests to the external server and handles the connection. It works on PHP level with mysqli commands.

In the repository classes I build the SQL string and call the helper utility to handle the connection. As results I return arrays.

Like this I am able to handle anything in my controller and with the FLUID mechanisms.

Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at dbal. Map you external database as dbal [handler](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/dbal/Configuration/Handlercfg/Index.html#using-another-mysql-database-for-the-tt-guest-and-sys-note-tables) and [map](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/dbal/Configuration/Mapping/Index.html#mapping-example) the needed table. And then use extbase and [map](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html#using-foreign-data-sources) the table to your objects.

Comment: I have to deal with JOINs and extbase query statements. As to my experience DBAL does not cooperate well with Extbase in these situations. I came in a big hazzle lately when using DBAL. I won't try it again, sorry.

Comment: As I know dbal ist the only official solution. Maybe you can wrote you own queries and database connection but as I know you cannot use the extbase "magics".  Maybe you can "sync" the data in your typo3 database, but then you have to manage that the data is actual and not fragmented with other database accesses.

Comment: I don't need the Extbase "magics" in the repository because I have no database. Remember that I am not allowed to store the data locally. I just have a set of SQL requests and I get some data in return. So no TYPO3 databse, no TCA, nothing. But I want to use Fluid and the action mechanism in the controller. For the repositories I need a way to define the database connection and to send SQL queries.

Comment: I could not find on time examples, but I think than "Storage Backends" should be what you want. An storage backend in none namespace style for ldap could be adapted to use an other database: http://xavier.perseguers.ch/en/tutorials/typo3/articles/ldap-backend-for-extbase.html

Answer (score 0):

While dbal is definitely the cleanest way, I also used a helper, cause some third party extensions in my system made the usage of dbal impossible.

You can instantiate a completely new db connection as a simple utility.

```
<?php
namespace FOO\YourExt\Utility;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

/**
 * Database utility
 */
class DatabaseUtility
{

    private static $config = 'External';

    /**
     * Instantiate custom queryBuilder for different database config
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public static function queryBuilder()
    {
        $cObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer');
        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
        $connectionPool = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Database\\ConnectionPool');
        $externalConnection = $connectionPool->getConnectionByName(self::$config);
        $queryBuilder = $externalConnection->createQueryBuilder();

        return $queryBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate custom connectionPool for different database config
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public static function connectionPool()
    {
        $cObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer');
        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
        $connectionPool = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Database\\ConnectionPool');
        $externalConnection = $connectionPool->getConnectionByName(self::$config);

        return $externalConnection;
    }
}
```

You can use any database connection defined in your `LocalConfiguration.php`.

```
[...]
    'DB' => [
        'Connections' => [
            'Default' => [],
            'External' => [
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'dbname' => 'external_database_name',
                'driver' => 'mysqli',
                'host' => '',
                'password' => '',
                'port' => 3306,
                'user' => '',
            ],
        ],
    ],

[...]
```